# How can I remove a specific line from a file only if there are other lines in the file?

Tags: text-processing, perl

How can I remove a specific line from a file ONLY if there are other lines in the file?

For example, don't touch this file:

```
cat file.txt
ASDF
```

but remove "ASDF" from this file:

```
cat file.txt
ASDF
TR422
```

Because it has other lines than "ASDF".

I'll welcome a solution in bash, perl or any other common tool.

Comment: What about a file that contains `hello ASDF`? Or a file that contains multiple `ASDF` lines but nothing else?

Comment: ASDF is always in the first line of the files, and matches this: "^ASDF$"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `bash`, using `sed`:

```
if [[ $(< "$file") != "ASDF" ]]; then
  sed -i '/^ASDF$/d' "$file"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file names don't contain newline characters, this will remove lines containing just `ASDF` from all files in the current directory, unless the file consists of a single line containing just `ASDF`. If your `sed` doesn't have the `-i` option, output to a temporary file and move it in place afterwards.

```
grep -l ASDF -- * | while IFS= read -r filename; do
  if ! echo 'ASDF' | cmp -s - "$filename"; then
    sed -i -e '/^ASDF$/d' -- "$filename"
  fi
done
```

Here's another approach, which removes the `ASDF` lines, and only overwrites the original file if the new file is neither empty nor identical to the original.

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp -p "$(dirname -- "$filename")")
sed '/^ASDF$/' <"$filename" >"$tmpfile"
if [ -s "$tmpfile" ] && ! cmp -s -- "$filename" "$filename"; then
  mv -f -- "$tmpfile" "$filename"
else
  rm -- "$tmpfile"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to look for the number of lines in the file.

Pseudocode:

```
if (numberOfLines > 1 && file.contains("ASDF")) {
    file.remove("ASDF");
}
```

Comment: what language is this? bash? perl?

Comment: It's pseudocode...

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version of [enzotib's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19611/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-string-from-a-file-only-if-there-are-other-lines-in-t/19614#19614):

```
[[ $(< "$file") != "ASDF" ]] && sed -i '/^ASDF$/d' "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this `sed`-only, no need for shell tests and whatnot:

```
sed '1{/^ASDF$/{$q;d;};}' infile
```